# Defining variables

Tags: variable-definitions

I want to define a variable for a set of computations to be a positive integer (or more generally, say I want to define it as integer or real, since Mathematica seems to take a variable as a complex one by definition). I am familiar with Fortran 95, where we define variables in the beginning to be integer or real, what is the corresponding set of command(s) in Mathematica for the same purpose. Thanks

Comment: Variables are all general type in Mathematica. There is no static typing of the kind your describe. Mathematica is a bit special in that it doesn't even check that a variable has any assigned value (being a symbolic language), but otherwise it treats its variable similar to, e.g., python. However, a good practice is to give the variable a name that makes it clear to you what type it is.

Comment: @b3m2a1 keeping in mind what you said, so is there any condition or assumption that I can put on the variables so as to make it, say a positive integer (or real)?

Comment: Outside of simply assigning a it a real or integer value? Not really. You can check the type using, e.g. [`Assert`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assert.html) and [`MatchQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatchQ.html). I think you might be well served by reading [a tutorial](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/). It'll clear up your confusions and help you get started with the language.

Comment: See the documentation for `IntegerQ` and `Element` for a partial answer to your question.

Comment: Assuming that `a` is such an integer, positive variable, try to evaluate `$Assumptions[a > 0, a \[Element] Integer];` in the very first cell of your notebook. Mma will know this definition through the whole session.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch thanks, i was more or less looking for something like this.

Comment: thanks everyone for the helpful comments. :)

Comment: What do you mean by "variable"?  Are you doing symbolic calculations, or numerical ones like in Fortran (which you mention)?  A symbolic "variable" is an entirely different concept from a variable in Fortran (which is just a container for a value).  I assume you mean symbolic one, in which case this is a duplicate.